# Throughput value in Aggregate Report

Tags: jmeter, load-testing, performance-testing, jmeter-plugins

I have few questions on the results captured in Aggregate report.

What does the values in the 'Total' row shows?
How it is projected?
Particularly as we concentrate more on the aggregate_report_rate (QPS) field,
Is the value of the aggregate_report_rate in the 'Total' row, calculate the exact QPS?
Is that value is what all we need to say as the exact QPS?

Can someone please clarify on the same?

Answer (score 0):

Aggregate report shows the Transactions per second(TPS) in the column aggregate_report_rate. For individual HTTP request names it shows TPS for that HTTP request itself. The total row shows the overall TPS for all the HTTP requests included in the test plan.

So, all the row show the average TPS for whole duration of the test, the total row shows the overall TPS of the test plan.